# Wouldn't be better if Windows used directx to draw stuff?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, gdi

Windows uses GDI to draw it's windows.  Directx is way faster than GDI.
Wouldn't be smart if they used Directx to draw all of the stuff?

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but doesn't Windows 7 use DirectX for its rendering, or at least a fast vector graphics API?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. That said, it's a fine question, but it doesn't belong here. I'm closing as off-topic but for SuperUser (although it's questionable whether it belongs there either).

Comment: I'm sure you realize that DirectX had not been invented when Windows and the GDI subsystem were written. Later versions of Windows have begun to take advantage of certain features of DirectX, but GDI is still there under the hood. It is responsible for **far** more things than getting graphics up on the screen. Device independent graphics is a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but the [Aero interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero#Requirements) that comes with Windows 7 requires a DirectX 9 compatible graphics processor with a Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) driver, Pixel shader 2.0 in hardware, and a minimum of 128 MB of Video RAM.

So I suspect DirectX is indeed used, at least partially, to render things in Windows 7.

In addition, [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) (WPF), the new graphical subsystem for rendering user interfaces in Windows-based applications, uses DirectX under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps the most significant capability of GDI over more direct methods of accessing the hardware is its scaling capabilities, and abstraction of target devices. Using GDI, it is very easy to draw on multiple devices, such as a screen and a printer, and expect proper reproduction in each case. This capability is at the center of all What You See Is What You Get applications for Microsoft Windows.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface

It sounds like, at least historically, GDI/GDI+ was more compatible with various hardware.

Windows 7 uses Aero and it does make use of DirectX.

> a DirectX 9 compatible graphics processor with a Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) driver, Pixel shader 2.0 in hardware, and a minimum of 128 MB of Video RAM
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero